# Haskell FFI: Interfacing with simple C++?

Tags: c++, haskell, ffi

From what I've read so far, using the FFI with C++ is very hard to accomplish. One of the biggest reasons seems to be converting C++ objects to Haskell. My problem now is that I don't have any experience with C, but a few years with C++, and also I prefer OOP. Therefore, I would naturally like to benefit from C++.

So can I write C++ programs designed to be used by the Haskell FFI to get around these problems? C++ could do anything under the hood, but the API would be C-like, i.e. I'm not exchanging objects, don't have overloaded top-level functions and so on. Are there any pitfalls to look out for?

(To compare my project with something you may be familiar with: Think of using SciPy's Weave to speed up Python code.)

Comment: If you want to use C++, then use C++, not Haskell. Otherwise reserve FFI for interfacing with native libraries and maaaaaybe really-performance-critical code.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Performance-critical code would be exactly what I'd be using C++ for.

Comment: Except FFI is used as last resort in that.

Comment: Yes. Can we focus on my question now?

Comment: The answer is 'yes, you can use extern "C"-d functions if you're careful', and not really related to Haskell.

Comment: There are quite a few pitfalls with using FFI with performance critical code, if there are others with using C++ than using 'plain' C I can only speculate in. If you can code your c++ in a thread  safe and reentrant way you should do that. Maybe you could elaborate somewhat your performance critical code would do?

Comment: A routine for solving a specific differential equation on a lattice, for example. Then there are other examples for which I've got the C++ code snippets already, and integrating that into a Haskell program is only a problem of interfacing. Think of what I'm trying to do like what you would use SciPy's Weave for when writing Python. (And you're right, side effects can be a big problem in C++/Haskell, however that's something always to be careful about.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use C++ code via the FFI if you expose a C API on top of that C++ code.

A common pattern is to simply wrap all of a class's "methods" as C procedures, such that objects of that class can be treated as opaque pointers that those functions can be applied to.

For example, given the code (`foo.h`):

```c
class foo
{
public:
  foo(int a) : _a(a) {}
  ~foo() { _a = 0; } // Not really necessary, just an example

  int get_a() { return _a; }
  void set_a(int a) { _a = a; }

private:
  int _a;
}
```

...you can easily create C versions of all of these methods (`foo_c.h`):

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef foo *foo_ptr;
extern "C"
{
#else
typedef void *foo_ptr;
#endif

foo_ptr foo_ctor(int a);
void foo_dtor(foo_ptr self);

int foo_get_a(foo_ptr self);
void foo_set_a(foo_ptr self, int a);
#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif
```

Then, there must be some adapter code that implements the C interface via the C++ interface (`foo_c.cpp`):

```c
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo_c.h"

foo_ptr foo_ctor(int a) { return new foo(a); }
void foo_dtor(foo_ptr self) { delete self; }

int foo_get_a(foo_ptr self) { return self->get_a(); }
void foo_set_a(foo_ptr self, int a) { self->set_a(a); }
```

The header `foo_c.h` can now be included in a Haskell FFI definition.

Comment: why void * in C? `typedef struct foo* foo_ptr;` works in both.

Comment: Because `foo` is a class and not a struct, and if you have a C++-aware C-compiler that lets you do that, it's extremely non-standard.

Comment: Every standard-compliant C++ compiler has to compile it when you address `class foo` as `struct foo` in some typedef.

Comment: Yes, but I won't be compiling C code with a C++ compiler, especially not when the C compiler is automatically invoked by Cabal.

Comment: You apparently have `#ifdef __cplusplus` in code so you apparently compile it with both compilers and `typedef struct foo* foo_ptr;` compiles into a pointer of `foo` in both compilers. You can not define `foo` in C and so you can not dereference the pointer to `foo` in C (or to do pointer arithmetics with it) but that you can't do with `void*` either.

Comment: @ÖöTiib yes, that is why I think void* is appropriate.

Comment: No it is not, because it is pointer to distinct type unlike `void*`. By your logic `fopen(filename,mode)` should return `void*` not `FILE*`.

Comment: We're talking about creating a Haskell FFI here, not making the ideal C API with const correctness and type validity and so on. It really doesn't matter.

Comment: You sound like Haskell is a trash that eats anything. As lot i know Haskell devs they are extremely conservative and would certainly like to separate two different opaque C structures from each other in their code.

Comment: Let's also add that exporting your C++ code with C like that, makes interoping with just about every other language much easier! not just Haskell (even between other OOP languages in my experience, C# and Java for example).